# Tar's -r flag name meaning

Tags: linux, shell, tar, archive

Why `tar` flag used to append file to the archive is named `-r`?

Other flags' names have some explanations (`-x` for eXtract, `-C` for Change current dir to another for output, ..) but I can't get how to explain `-r`.

Comment: Single letter option names are a limited set. Sometimes, programmers have to pick suboptimal choices. `tar` uses `-a` for `auto-compress` so it's not available for "`append`". Look at all the single letter options in `man tar`, `info tar` or `tar --help`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the idea of `tar` (tape archive) is that the medium it's written to is only writable linearly. Hence, the `tar` [format](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD+7.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html#SEE_ALSO) supports for the same paths being added to the same archive multiple times, with the later appended versions **replacing** the earlier (both in time and storage position). That's where `-r` comes from: it's not *append*, it's *replace*.

A witness of that original meaning would be found in this old [solaris/ sunOS5 man page](http://software.cfht.hawaii.edu/man/solaris/tar(1)):

> **r**
>        Replace. The named files are written at the end of the tarfile.

This might hail from `tar`'s "loose predecessor", [`tp`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_7th/1/tp)

Comment: so `-r`'s original meaning is "replace older archive with the newer version which includes appended files", right?

Comment: no. It means "replace the file already in the existing archive by appending a new version to the end of the archive".

Comment: Also note that older `tar` (I mean you, Solaris 2!) had no feature to select between version of files with the same name. If you had three versions of `foo.txt`, it would restore all three of them as it found them. The `replacement` happened on restore, not when the archive was appended to.